# Importing a page from another component in Nextjs app router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am using nextjs app router. and i have this folder strucutre:

```
app/
├─ /companies/
│  ├─ page.tsx
├─ /administrators/
│  ├─ page.tsx
```

I am trying to import **companies/page.tsx** component inside the **administrators/page.tsx** component.

The purpose is i have a small modal that opens and it shows a portal view for the companies page.

In context, it works perfectly during development, however, after the building phase, Nextjs throws an error:

```
Type error: Page "src/app/companies/page.tsx" has an invalid "default" export:
  Type "CompaniesPageProps" is not valid.
```

The code I have for the companies component is this:

```
export interface CompaniesPageProps {
  onSaveSuccess?: ()=> void
}
const CompaniesPage = (props: CompaniesPageProps)=> {
  // ... etc some logic, then: onSaveSuccess.?("hi")
  return <p>Hello world</p>
}
export default CompaniesPage
```

And this is the administrators page:

```
import CompaniesPage from '@/companies/page.tsx'

const AdministratorsPage = ()=> {
  return (
   <div>
    <button onClick={openModal}>click me</button>
    <Modal open={isOpen}>
      <CompaniesPage onSaveSuccess={()=> closeModal()}>
    </Modal>
   </div>
  )

}

export default AdministratorsPage
```

Comment: Add the `'use client'` directive at the top of `companies/page.tsx` and after that Use `import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'` within AdministratorsPage and use `const DynamicCompaniesPage = dynamic(() => import('../companies/page'), {
  ssr: false,
});` to prevent its inclusion in the initial server-side bundle. hope it will resolve. 

If this way does not resolve the issue, then share your `next.config.js` file and folder structure. The folder structure will start from `pages`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest pulling the page contents for companies page out into a Companies.tsx component that both administrators/page.tsx and companies/pages.tsx use. That's what we've done for a similar situation and it works fine.

Comment: Alright, to make it cooler, I made two files in the `companies/` directory, I made `page.tsx` and `_page.tsx` - where `_page.tsx` is the whole code of the page, while `page.tsx` is just a component that imports and returns the `_page.tsx`. This way - when I need the companies page inside the administrators page, I am importing the `_page.tsx` component file. 